# Hook into PrintWriter and modify the string

Tags: servlets, hook, printwriter, printstream

how to change the String of printwriter out.print before it print on the  screen

i test it for system.out.print it  works  but  i m in J2EE environment

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzU0K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you upload some of your code.
Your question can be answered more accurately if you give some code.

Comment: i add and img   that explain what i want  i just dont  find a way to do that